# SQL using the WHERE clause for the first column only

Tags: sql, where-clause, case-when

I have a table with columns:

```
customer_id, 
customer_name,
transaction_number, 
transaction_date,
transaction_type,
transaction_value,
transaction_approved.
```

I am trying to generate a list where the columns are

```
customer_id,
customer_name,
total transaction value
```

where the `transaction_type` is credit and made in 2020, total transaction value where the `transaction_type` is debit or cash in 2019.

However, this list is only including the `customer_id` who made at least one transaction using credit in the year 2020. Basically, how would I use the where clause to get the criteria for the `customer_id` and then get the rest of the list based on those `customer_ids` only?

It would be returning

- the `customer_id` where the at least one transaction was made using credit in the year 2019
- and then the other columns next to it would return the values for that `customer_id`

Comment: Not clear to me.  Please add sample input and output data.

Comment: And please also show us the code you've written so far

Comment: Do you have a table listing existing `customer_ids`?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from above description, user needs customers which has transaction_type credit in 2020, but he wants sum of amount for year 2019 and that also for transaction type debit and cash . Please update question if its not the case

```
select 
    customer_id, customer_name,
    sum(coalesce(transaction_value,0)) as total_transaction_value 
from 
    table_T 
where 
    customer_id in (select distinct customer_id from table_T 
                    where transaction_type = 'credit'  
                      and transaction_date >= '2020-01-01')
    and transaction_date >= '2019-01-01'  
    and transaction_date < '2020-01-01' 
    and transaction_type in ('debit', 'cash')
group by  
    customer_id, customer_name
```

Database is not mentioned you may have to parse date field accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
select customer_id, customer_name, sum(effective_value)
    from (
        select customer_id, customer_name,
                case
                    when transaction_type in ('debit', 'cash')
                            and '2019' <= transaction_date
                            and transaction_date < '2020'
                        then transaction_value
                    else 0
                END effective_value
            from transactions as T
    ) as T
    group by customer_id, customer_name;
```

You'll have to adapt the `transaction_date` comparision to meet your database syntax.